# Forwarding www traffic through a remote computer

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, iptables, socks5

I am far from being an expert in networking so please be gentle. I did a part of this setup successfully before, following a tutorial on a certain website, which I cannot find anymore. I have two computers, let's name them HOME and LAB. LAB is in other part of the city where I live and the HOME computer is at my home. LAB has a public IP address, is a computer with Manjaro Linux installation, and is suited in the university network. I want to be able to access the university resources from my HOME through my LAB computer, e.g. to access paid scientific journals, etc. In other words I want to tunnel all my www trafic through the path: (Firefox on HOME) -> (Lab) -> (journals and univ. resources). I did the following steps but it seems that something is still missing:

1. `ssh -D 1234 username@LAB` from my HOME computer, where username is substituted by my real username and LAB is the public IP of the LAB computer.
2. On the LAB computer I made the following iptables rules/command:

   ```
   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   iptables -F -t nat
   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:80
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
   ```
3. In the settings of Firefox browser on the HOME computer I checked Global/Network Settings/Manual proxy Configuration/Socks v5 and typed `localhost` in the field `SOCKS Host` and `1234` in the field `Port`.
4. After these steps I cannot access any website.

Note that I use Windows 10 and WSL 1 (Windows Subsystem for Linux) on HOME computer to ssh to LAB, but I think it makes no difference.
I believe some iptables rules and/or something more are still missing. What is missing?

Comment: What is step 2 supposed to achieve?

Comment: @u1686_grawity For me step 2 looks like setting up the traffic forwarding rules. I remember these are mandatory but some additional iptables lines are necessary.

Comment: But what is it forwarding where? The "MASQUERADE" rule would make sense if your server was forwarding IP traffic – which it is _not_ – but the "DNAT" rule is entirely nonsensical in the context.

Comment: If faced with network strangeness, use a packet sniffer to see what's happening! // Does your LAB computer perhaps have to use a proxy to browse to HTTP or HTTPS sites? Also please clarify what "cannot access" means. Timeout? Host not found? …?

Comment: @u1686_grawity As I said I do not know much about masquerade-ing, dnat and other networking technologies/terms. So, I can't answer your question. Importantly it works when port 1234 is changed to another one, since something already uses this port number on my HOME PC. I will check out as problem solved.

Comment: @DanielB The problem was with port 1234, which was already used on my HOME PC. Changing the port number solves the original issue. I will mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure given in the original post is sufficient for forwarding world wide web traffic through a remote computer. Something else blocks the port that I used, port 1234, on the HOME computer (Windows 10 machine). Other port (e.g. I tried 4321) solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the below would help, have not looked into Mankato (use Ubuntu servers myself).
For a similar scenario (access to homelab resources on the move) I've configured openVPN on one of my servers, perhaps a option for you?

Found the below for Mankato;
https://snapcraft.io/install/easy-openvpn-server/manjaro

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I used before openVPN too, but found the "ssh -D" way much easier to config and use.